# Como declarar um array multidimensional usando new

Tags: array, c++, array-multidimensional, declaração-de-variável

Como eu declaro um array multidimensional usando new ?
Um array normal seria assim:

```
int* ponteiro = new int[5];
```

Mas

```
int* ponteiro = new int[5][5];
```

não compila ! mas

```
int array[5][5];
```

funciona perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A melhor forma para declarar o *array* multidimensional é declarar um array de ponteiros para cada nível e inicializar o nível dentro de um *looping*.

Exemplo para `ponteiro[30][100]`:

```
// Declara e cria o primeiro nível como ponteiro duplo de 30 elementos
int **ponteiro = new int*[30];

// Para cada item, cria um vetor de 100 elementos
for(int i=0; i<30; i++)
    ponteiro[i] = new int[100];
```

E o código para desalocar o *array*:

```
// Desaloca cada um dos items
for(int i=0; i<30; i++)
    delete ponteiro[i];

// Desaloca a variável ponteiro
delete ponteiro;
```

Para *arrays* com uma dimensão variável, é possível utilizar a sintaxe:

```
int (*ponteiro)[100] = new int[30][100];
```

E caso esteja compilando o programa para o padrão c++2011 (ou superior), é possível inicializar diretamente os arrays internos dentro de uma lista extendida, com a sintaxe (exemplo para `[3][2]`):

```
int **ponteiro = new int*[3]{ new int[2], new int[2], new int[2] };
```

Independente da forma de declaração, é importante lembrar sempre de desalocar a memória com `delete`.